# Access to resize Qr image

Tags: html, asp.net, qr-code

```
using IronBarCode;
GeneratedBarcode barcode = QRCodeWriter.CreateQrCodeWithLogo("3255842", @"stack.jpg", 500);
ser.InnerHtml += barcode.ToHtmlTag();
```

How can I access and resize the logo image?

Answer (score 0):

You can size your logo before loading, or logo you specify in the IronBarcode `QRCodeWriter.CreateQrCodeWithLogo` method will automatically be sized appropriately and snapped to the QR grid.

The [Advanced QR Code Writing](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/barcode/examples/advanced-qr-code-writing/) code example shows the additional QR creation options exposed when using `QRCodeWriter` instead of `BarcodeWriter.CreateBarcode`

See the code example below:

```
using IronBarCode;
GeneratedBarcode QRWithLogo = QRCodeWriter.CreateQrCodeWithLogo("3255842", @"stack.jpg");

//can also set margins, background color 
QRWithLogo.ResizeTo(500, 500).SetMargins(10).ChangeBarCodeColor(Color.DarkGreen);

ser.InnerHtml += QRWithLogo.ToHtmlTag();
```

Disclaimer: I work for Iron Software.